# Как оптимизировать анимацию по hover (css / html / jquery)?

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-animation

Написал анимацию выпадающего списка меню при hover на его родителя.

В общей 'конструкции' есть одна существенная проблема - наведите на родителя несколько раз подряд и Вы увидите, что не всегда показывается выпадающий список. Пока его первая функция+анимация не отработает до конца, вторая не начнется.

**Вопрос:** как оптимизировать код так, чтобы он реагировал 'выпадением' списка по каждому hover родителя?

```js
$(function()
{

    $.fn.extend({
        animateCss: function(animationName, callback) {
            var animationEnd = (function(el) {
                var animations = {
                    animation: 'animationend',
                    OAnimation: 'oAnimationEnd',
                    MozAnimation: 'mozAnimationEnd',
                    WebkitAnimation: 'webkitAnimationEnd',
                };

                for (var t in animations) {
                    if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
                        return animations[t];
                    }
                }
            })(document.createElement('div'));

            this.addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
                $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);

                if (typeof callback === 'function') callback();
            });

            return this;
        },
    });

    $('#yourElement').animateCss('bounce', function() {

    });


    $('.nav__item.dropdown').hover(
        function(){

            var dropdown = $(this).find('>.nav');
            dropdown.removeClass('hide');
            dropdown.addClass('show');
            $(dropdown).animateCss('fadeInUp');

        },
        function(){

            var dropdown = $(this).find('>.nav');

            $(dropdown).animateCss('fadeOutDown', function() {
                dropdown.removeClass('show');
                dropdown.addClass('hide');
            });

        }
    )
});
```

```css
.show
{
  display: block;
}

.hide
{
  display: none;
}

.test ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: initial;
  margin-bottom: initial;
  margin-left: initial;
  margin-right: initial;
  -webkit-padding-start: initial;
}

.test .nav.parents
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.test .nav.parents > .nav__item
{
  padding: 10px;
  background: salmon;
}

.test .nav.parents > .nav__item.dropdown > .nav
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: initial;
  margin-bottom: initial;
  margin-left: initial;
  margin-right: initial;
  -webkit-padding-start: initial;

  position: absolute;
}

.test .nav.parents > .nav__item.dropdown > .nav > .nav__item
{
  padding: 5px;
  background: rosybrown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<div class="test">
  <ul class="nav parents">
    <li class="nav__item">Parent 1</li>
    <li class="nav__item dropdown">
      Parent 2
      <ul class="nav hide">
        <li class="nav__item">Child 1</li>
        <li class="nav__item">Child 2</li>
        <li class="nav__item">Child 3</li>
        <li class="nav__item">Child 4</li>
        <li class="nav__item">Child 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">Parent 3</li>
    <li class="nav__item dropdown">
      Parent 4
      <ul class="nav hide">
        <li class="nav__item">Child 1</li>
        <li class="nav__item">Child 2</li>
        <li class="nav__item">Child 3</li>
        <li class="nav__item">Child 4</li>
        <li class="nav__item">Child 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">Parent 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понятно для чего нужен jQuery , это вполне делается без js вообще

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #fbfbfb;
}

ul li ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translate(0, 100px)scale(1.2);
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s .4s;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

ul li ul li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  transform: translate(0, 20px)scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility:visible;
}

a {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: blue;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.drop:after {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.drop:hover:after {
  content: "-";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
  <li class="drop"><a href="">item2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">item2-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2-3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2-4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item2-5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
  <li class="drop"><a href="">item4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">item4-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item4-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item4-3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item4-4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">item4-5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus animi debitis ea dolore suscipit dolor minus nesciunt eum distinctio voluptates ex dicta perspiciatis placeat culpa sit aut, beatae quae earum?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Используется библиотека `animate.css`, JS нужен, чтобы можно было по событию вешать определенную анимацию элементу...

Comment: кстати, в Вашем примере выпадающий список можно вызвать не наводя курсор на его родителя...

Comment: В Вашем примере с выпадающим списком можно взаимодействовать даже тогда, когда он якобы не активен. Наведите курсор на 100px ниже родителя и список появится.

Comment: Да, visibility выручил :) "тут 90% анимаций на css3 сделаны" - все 100%. Просто есть библиотека и хотелось ее юзать без внесения изменений в нее / ее использования. Но пока и в правду склоняюсь к тому, что проще прописать стили анимации самому элементу в css без использования js...

Comment: Имеется библиотека Animate.css, при наведение на родителя js цепляет класс-анимации выпадающему списку и список с нужной анимацией появляется (и убирается). Но в js есть проблема, пока первая анимация (появления) не отработает до конца, вторая анимация (скрытия) не запуститься, даже если уже мы отвели курсор от родителя.

Comment: @MikeRo это вы таким способом делаете появление скрытых пунктов или что то другое ?

Comment: Да. Разрабом библиотеки был представлен js код, который отслеживает окончание анимации скрытия списка и лишь после этого вешает списку display: none;

Comment: Хорошо, представим задачу: Допустим у нас есть элемент, который можно прятать способом visibility: hidden;, но он остается в dom и занимает место собой, хоть мы его и не видим. А если его нужно вообще убрать так, чтобы он места не занимал, например display: none;, то как с анимацией прятать элементы в таком случае?

Comment: В том и дело, а как тогда скрыть элемент так, чтобы это было с анимацией и чтобы он не занимал визуально пространство на сайте? Вот в animate.css + js функции, который разраб написал, он показывает, как вначале отыграть анимацию и следом за ней присвоить элементу display: none;